# Partitioning Help

Tags: installation, partitioning

Does Ubuntu partition drives when you install it alongside Windows 7? I remember reading that the maximum partition allowed is 4 (or something)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu partitions drives when you install it alongside Windows.

Master Boot Record (MBR) disks use the standard BIOS partition table. GUID Partition Table (GPT) disks use Unified Extensible Firmware Interface (UEFI). Hard disk drives that use Master Boot Record partitioning can have a maximum of 4 primary partitions. One of the primary partitions can be an extended partition. An extended partition can contain any number of logical partitions.

Disk drives that are formatted with GPT Partitioning can have 128 partitions by default. GPT drives have the advantage of being able to boot from hard disk drives that are larger than 2TB.

Comment: Does ubuntu make a logical partition? There's already 4 partitions in my computer so I might not be able to install..

Comment: You need to visit the [Ubuntu Official Documentation Pre-Partitioning for Multi-Boot Systems](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/non-debian-partitioning.html) website. Don't manually partition anything until you're sure you know what you're doing. Download a copy of the Gparted iso and burn it to a CD or make a bootable live USB with it. Get a flash drive with no important files on it and learn about manual partitioning by creating example partitions on the flash drive.